# Capitalize every letter after / and - characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to capitalize every letter after a `/` or `-` character. Meaning, if given the string

```
this/is/a/pretty-cool/url
```

Its expected output would look like

```
This/Is/A/Pretty-Cool/Url
```

My code:

```
string = string.replace(/\/(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g, function(i,e) { return '/'+e.toUpperCase() });
```

Which currently returns

```
this/Is/A/Pretty-cool/Url
```

Not quite there, obviously.

How can I get this to work as expected?

Comment: your problem statement is incomplete - you also appear to want to capitalise the _first_ character found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you have a simple solution:

```
string = string.replace(/(^|\/|-)(\S)/g, s=>s.toUpperCase())
```

You just match one character after either the start of the string, a `/` or a `-`. It's simple because there's no problem uppercasing one of those chars (`'/'.toUpperCase()` is `'/'`).

Now, let's imagine that you don't want to uppercase the first part (maybe it's different in your real problem, maybe you care about that poor function which has to uppercase a `"/"`), then you would have used submatches like this:

```
string = string.replace(/(^|\/|-)(\S)/g, (_,a,b)=>a+b.toUpperCase())
```

(but you don't have to go to such extremities here)

Comment: To the downvoter: please enlighten me, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your code you have missing the `-` char.

So, changing the code to support the char you can use:

```
var string = string.replace(/(^|\/|-)(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g, function(i,e) { return i.charAt(0)+e.toUpperCase() });
```

or

```
var string = string.replace(/(^|\/|-)(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g, function(i,e) { return i.toUpperCase() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant, which uppercases after *any* non-word character, and also at the start of the string:

```
string = string.replace(/(^|\W)(\w)/g, (match, a, b) => a + b.toUpperCase());
```

(or using the same short cut as @DenysSéguret):

```
string = string.replace(/(^|\W)(\w)/g, s => s.toUpperCase());
```